# Lookupvalue in Range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new in Power  BI. I am just going through an article which calculates Moving Average. I would like to know what is happening in `LOOKUPVALUE` function.

Anyone could tell us `EARLIER ( Prices[DayNumber] ) – 8`. What it is exactly? It subtract the value `EARLIER ( Prices[DayNumber] ) - 8` or show the range from `Prices[DayNumber]` to `8`. And what in the case when `EARLIER ( Prices[DayNumber] )  = 2`? What it is returned?

```
Prices[MovingAverage200] =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Prices[Close] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Prices[Date] ),
        AND (
            Prices[Date]
                >= LOOKUPVALUE (
                    Prices[Date],
                    Prices[Stock], EARLIER ( Prices[Stock] ),
                    Prices[DayNumber], EARLIER ( Prices[DayNumber] ) – 8
                ),
            Prices[Date] <= EARLIER ( Prices[Date] )
        )
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Prices, Prices[Stock] )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOOKUPVALUE` is searching through the values in the column `Prices[Date]` looking row by row through the table `Prices` where the `Stock` value in that row matches the value in the current row, that is, `EARLIER( Prices[Stock] )`, and where the `DayNumber` in that row matches the value in the current row minus 8 days, that is, `EARLIER( Prices[DayNumber]) - 8`.

Note that the `EARLIER` function has nothing to do with time. It refers to the earlier ***row context***. Since you are within an iterator function `FILTER` and then also inside `LOOKUPVALUE`, you need the `EARLIER` function to specify that you are talking about the column within the context of the outer function instead of the inner one.

---

What this measure does overall is average the `Close` value for all dates between `Date - 8 days` and `Date` (inclusive) and for all rows matching the current `Stock`.

Comment: thanks for answering the question. i would like to know if EARLIER( Prices[DayNumber]) = 2.in this case 2-8 =-6 then no value with DayNumber .then what it is return

Comment: If there are no corresponding dates to find, then the `LOOKUPVALUE` will return a blank. Since `Prices[Date] >= BLANK()` returns `True`, only the other part of your `AND` applies.